# Why does Bluecove require libbluetooth-dev package installed to run

Tags: java, linux, bluetooth, bluecove

I'm just setting up [Bluecove](https://code.google.com/p/bluecove/) on an Ubuntu system and I see buried down in the wiki for the Linux BlueZ stack that it [requires a dev package to be installed for it to work correctly.](https://code.google.com/p/bluecove/wiki/stacks)

I understood that a dev package is only required if I need the headers for compiling my own C/C++ code to use the Bluecove native library. If I'm only compiling Java code then surely the development package is not needed? (It's effectively seen as an application using the Bluecove native library). Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though the package `libbluetooth3` doesn't include the `.so` link to the specific library when it is installed. (Use `dpkg-query`).

The Bluecove JARs contain JNI libraries that are linked against the the `.so` file (confirmed using `ldconfig`). I found that only `libbluetooth-dev` contains the `.so` so for would be the only way for the uninitiated to get Bluecove to work.

I resolved the issue by creating the soft-link manually, the package `libbluetooth3` installed.